# how do i use variables in the ping command (batch)

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file where the user inputs a specific site and the file pings it.

```
@echo off
set /p id="Select the site you would like to ping: "
echo Pinging site...
ping &id&
pause
```

Comment: in batch, variables are referenced as `%id%`, not `&id&`.

Comment: Type `set /?` for help.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use % instead of & when using variables

```
@echo off

set /p id="Select the site you would like to ping: "

echo Pinging site...

ping %id%

pause
```